# How to add delay in Micro secs in tcl file?

Tags: scripting, tcl

I am using `when` command in tcl file, and after the condition is met I want to wait for some microseconds. I have found `after`, but the delay we specify for `after` is in milliseconds; it is not taking decimal values.

So is there any other way to add short delay in tcl file?

Comment: As Donal writes, there is no Tcl native way, but depending on the actual requirements, check out https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/ozhaYjgyEQw

Answer (score 1):

There's no native operation for that. If it is critical, you could busy-loop looking at `clock microseconds`…

```
proc microsleep {micros} {
    set expiry [expr {$micros + [clock microseconds]}]
    while {[clock microseconds] < $expiry} {}
}
```

I don't really recommend doing this as it is not energy efficient; such high precision waiting is rarely required in my experience (unless you're working on an embedded system with realtime requirements, an area where Tcl isn't a perfect fit).

Of course, you can also make a C wrapper round a system call like `nanosleep()`, and that might or might not be a better choice (and might or might not be more efficient)…

Comment: thanks for the reply . Yes i am working in VLSI Industry , while doing some forces i need to wait some micro secs before doing the force .